# Karma tests running twice

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

We have an Angular project with unit tests in jasmine. I'm having a problem that every time I save a file, all my unit tests are being run twice (using autowatch).

I've found this article which shows a similar problem: https://pracucci.com/avoid-karma-tests-run-twice-on-autowatch.html. Since our files are in Typescript, I tried this:

```
{ pattern: "**/*.ts", watched: false, served: true, included: true }
```

, but that doesn't work if I set my files pattern to Typescript. It gave the following error:
WARN [middleware:karma]: Invalid file type (ts), defaulting to js.

This is my karma.conf.js file:

```html
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config)
{
    config.set({
        basePath                : '',
        frameworks              : ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
        plugins                 : [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
            require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
            require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
            require('karma-junit-reporter')
        ],
        client                  : {
            clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
        },
        coverageIstanbulReporter: {
            dir                  : require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
            reports              : ['html', 'cobertura', 'lcovonly'],
            fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
        },
        jasmine: {
            random: false
        },
        junitReporter: {
            outputdir: '',
            outputFile: 'test-angular.xml'
        },
        reporters               : ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'junit'],
        port                    : 9876,
        colors                  : true,
        logLevel                : config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch               : true,
        autoWatchBatchDelay     : 10000,
        browsers                : ['Chrome'],
        singleRun               : false,
        files: [
            { pattern: '../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css', included: true, watched: true }
        ]
    });
};
```

This is my angular.json file:

```html
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "fuse": {
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "projectType": "application",
            "prefix": "app",
            "schematics": {
                "@schematics/angular:component": {
                    "styleext": "scss"
                }
            },
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "src/styles.scss",
                            "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css"
                        ],
                        "scripts": [
                            "node_modules/highcharts/highstock.js",
                            "node_modules/highcharts/modules/exporting.js"
                        ],
                        "showCircularDependencies": false
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                                }
                            ],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "aot": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "budgets": [
                                {
                                    "type": "initial",
                                    "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                                    "maximumError": "5mb"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "ec": {
                            "sourceMap": true,
                            "extractCss": true
                        },
                        "hmr": {
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.hmr.ts"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "fuse:build"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "fuse:build:production"
                        },
                        "hmr": {
                            "hmr": true,
                            "browserTarget": "fuse:build:hmr"
                        },
                        "ec": {
                            "browserTarget": "fuse:build:ec"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "fuse:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "codeCoverage": false,
                        "codeCoverageExclude": ["src/@fuse/**/*"],
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
                        "styles": [
                            "src/styles.scss"
                        ],
                        "scripts": [],
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": [
                            "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                            "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
                        ],
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "fuse-e2e": {
            "root": "e2e/",
            "projectType": "application",
            "prefix": "",
            "architect": {
                "e2e": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                    "options": {
                        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                        "devServerTarget": "fuse:serve"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "devServerTarget": "fuse:serve:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "defaultProject": "fuse"
}
```

This is my tests.ts file:

```html
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
    BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: any;

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
    BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules
context.keys().map(context);
```

How can I fix Karma to only run unit tests once on a change?

Comment: Why is the `indigo-pink.css` included in karma.conf? What happens, if you remove the `files` with this include to the `node_modules`? I'm not sure if this helps, but it is strange, that we have this file include here.

Comment: What is in your angular.json? Specifically there should be a section named test that links to your karma.conf.js as well as test.ts files. Also what it in your test.ts? In the newer versions of angular this is what points to the files to run, and it should definite look something like 'const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);' which says to load any file that ends with '.spec.ts'. Also, if you open dev tools in chrome while it runs tests, do you see any errors in console?

Comment: @tenkmilan I removed the files section like you suggested, but no change. everything still runs twice

Comment: @WesleyTrantham I added the 2 files you suggested in my original question. they seem to be in order. Do you see anything that could cause this?

Comment: We fixed this by upgrading to the latest version of Karma

Answer (score 1):

Update to latest version of Angular fixed it